# Fastest way to get expanded versions of 5 million shortened urls

Tags: python, url, multiprocessing, urllib2

I am working on a project where I need to expand 5 million shortened urls. These urls may be shortened by any url shortener. What is the fastest way to do this?

Current Code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2
import threading
import time



def urlResolution(url,tweetId,w):

    try:

        print "Entered Function"
        print "Original Url:",url

        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

        #header has been added since some sites give an error otherwise
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
        temp = urlopen(req)
        newUrl = temp.geturl()
        print "Resolved Url:",newUrl
        if newUrl!= 'None':
            print "in if condition"
            w.writerow([tweetId,newUrl])

    except Exception,e:
        print "Throwing exception"
        print str(e)
        return None


def urlResolver(urlFile):
    df=pd.read_csv(urlFile, delimiter="\t")

    df['Url']
    df2 = df[["Tweet ID","Url"]].copy()
    start = time.time()

    df3 = df2[df2.Url!="None"]

    list_url = []
    n=0
    w = csv.writer(open("OUTPUT_FILE.tsv", "w"), delimiter = '\t')
        w.writerow(["Tweet ID","Url"])

    maxC = 0
    while maxC < df3.shape[0]:
        #creates threads
        #only 40 threads are created at a time, since for large number of threads it gives <too many open files> error
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=urlResolution, args=(df3.iloc[n]['Url'],df3.iloc[n]['Tweet ID'],w)) for n in range(maxC,maxC+40)]


        for thread in threads:
                thread.start()
        for thread in threads:
                thread.join()
        if maxC+40 >= df3.shape[0]:
            threads = [threading.Thread(target=urlResolution, args=(df3.iloc[n]['Url'],df3.iloc[n]['Tweet ID'],w)) for n in range(maxC,df3.shape[0])]

                    print "threads complete"
                    for thread in threads:
                            thread.start()
                    for thread in threads:
                            thread.join()   
            break
        maxC = maxC + 40
    print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)

    w.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    df3 = urlResolver("INPUT_FILE.tsv")
```

I have written a multiprocessing program in python using urllib2(for url expansion), however it seems to be really slow.

Any tips on how to speed it up further?

Comment: Well firstly StackOverflow isn't the place for such questions it might be better to ask the folks over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and secondly you'd have to provide the actual code.

Comment: You’ll want to keep your connections alive, reusing them for new requests, and also pipeline your requests (send them in large batches without waiting for responses in between). That might require bypassing urllib2 and just interacting with a socket or a TLS wrapper around one.